# How to filter out specific keys from object using Ramda?

Tags: javascript, object, functional-programming, ramda.js

http://ramdajs.com/0.21.0/docs/#prop

[Ramda Repl](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?var%20myObject%20%3D%20%7Ba%3A%201%2C%20b%3A%202%2C%20c%3A%203%2C%20d%3A%204%7D%3B%0A%0Avar%20newObject%20%3D%20R.filter%28R.props%28%27a%27%29%2C%20myObject%29%3B%0A%2F%2Fvar%20newObject%20%3D%20R.filter%28R.equals%28R.props%28%27a%27%29%29%2C%20myObject%29%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log%28%27newObject%27%2C%20newObject%29%3B)

```
var myObject = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4};

var newObject = R.filter(R.props('a'), myObject);
//var newObject = R.filter(R.equals(R.props('a')), myObject);

console.log('newObject', newObject);
```

Right now the code above is returning the entire object:

`newObject
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4}`

What I would like to do is just return a new object with just the `'a'` key. Or a new object with the `a` and `b` keys.

Comment: You want back an object with just the key you want?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [pick](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#pick):

```
let newObj = R.pick(['a'], oldObj);
```

If your filtering criteria is more complex than just existence, you can use [pickBy](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#pickBy) to select via arbitrary predicate functions.

Answer (score 10):

The answer from Jared Smith is great.  I just wanted to add a note on why your code did not work.  You tried

```
R.filter(R.props('a'), {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4});
```

First of all, you pointed to the documentation for [`prop`](http://ramdajs.com/0.21.0/docs/#prop), but used [`props`](http://ramdajs.com/0.21.0/docs/#props).  These are different, but related, functions.  `prop` looks like

```
// prop :: k -> {k: v} -> v
prop('c', {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}); //=> 3
```

(there is some added complexity regarding `undefined`.)

`props` on the other hand takes multiple values

```
// props :: [k] -> {k: v} -> [v]
props(['a', 'd'], {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}); //=> [1, 4]
```

But neither of these is going to be useful input to `filter`, which for these purposes we can think of as

```
// filter :: (k -> Bool) -> {k: v} -> {k: v}
```

The first parameter to `filter` is a function from a (string) key to a boolean; it works with Javascript's idea that everything is truth-y except for a few specific values.  It will be called with each key in turn.  So for example, when deciding whether to include `{c: 3}`, it calls `props('a')('c')`, which for another slightly odd reason<sup>*</sup>, actually works, returning `[3]`, which is treated as truth-y, and the filter function will include `{c: 3}` in its output.  So too every key will be included.

---

<sup>*</sup> The reason `props('a', obj)` works when it really should be `props(['a'], obj)` is that in JS, strings are close enough to lists, having a `length` property and indexed values.  `'a'.length; ==> 1`, `'a'[0]; //=> 'a'`.  Hence `props` can treat single-character strings as though they were one-element lists of character strings.  But it can be a bit bizarre, too:  `R.props('cabby', {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}); //=> [3, 1, 2, 2, undefined]`.

Answer (score 5):

## [pickBy()](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pickBy)

```js
const getOnlyGoods = R.pickBy((_, key) => key.includes('good'));

const onlyGoods = getOnlyGoods({
  "very good":    90,
  "good":         80,
  "good enough":  60,
  "average":      50,
  "bad":          30,
  "":           10,
});

console.log(onlyGoods);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the other answers, there's also [omit](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#omit) to filter **out** specific props.

```
omit(["a"], { a: 1, b: 2 }) // -> { b: 2 }
```